# How to abort SMS receiving broadcast if user choose Yes in the dialog?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an application, which shows Dialog to the user when SMS is received. Depending on user's reply (Yes/No) I should either `abortBroadcast()` or not. I show Dialog in the separate activity. How could I abort broadcast from that activity? Or, alternatively, if I abort it in the receiver, how could I continue it there?

Comment: If I would be a user of your such type of app, I will blacklist without install. Are you playing with user, with such type of functionality?

Comment: @PankajKumar, why do you think so? This is the application to detect spam messages and blacklist the sender, if user confirms. Understand, that I should use notifications instead. But this is just a prototype...

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by more easy way

- First show Dialog without aborting the broadcast.
- Then if user click "NO" then delete the message from the phone inbox from the Activity.

by this way you no need to call `abortBroadcast()` at all.